In hetero (homodyne) detection, what does it mean to operate at the quantum shot limit?
I am an electrical engineering by trade, working on the analogue part (Transmitter & Receiver) of a quantum optical communication channel. By this, I mean I have not much experience on things quantum.
There are, however, some notions or concepts that I would like to understand, but no matter how much I read articles I don't seem to be able to get a clear answer.
My question would be:

What does it mean for a hetero- or homodyne receiver to be operating in the Quantum Shot Noise limit?

There are some notions that I have (I don't know if my assumptions are wrong).

Shot noise is caused by the uneven production/arrival of photons. When the rate of arrival is high enough, we can model this noise as following a Gaussian distribution. If the rate is low (related to the power of the laser, I wager in relation to the Local Oscillator (LO)), we have to model it as a Poisson distribution.
Dark current of photodetectors can also be modelled as such.
It is important to operate near the Shot Noise Limit. I don't know exactly why, but some potential hypothesis:

It limits/allows the elimination of electrical noise in post-processing
Uncorrelates LO power with signal power, facilitating detection of states
Simply improves detection by reducing overall noise floor (the more power, the more shot noise)



At the end of the end, what I would like to know is:

Is the shot noise limit in such a configuration absolute or relative? That is, does it depend on the power level of the LO, or is it a fixed value (beyond physical parameters of the system) that one approaches as the power level of the LO is reduced?
What would be a formula for determining what the power level of the LO should be for the system to be operating at the Shot Noise Limit?

Apologies if this is too long.
